# if Label.text! == "ほげ " でエラーにならないのに実行はされないのはなぜですか?

Tags: swift

タイトルとは少し違いますが下記のコードの　`if cell.skillName.text! == i { print("確認３") }`
のコードでデバックエリアに「確認３」と出力したいのですが出ない理由はなんですか

**確認のコード**

```swift
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    var array : Array<String> = ["\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "fastTitleKey") as! String)"]

    let arrayNameKey = "arrayNameKey"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! costomViewCell

        cell.skillName.text = "\(array[indexPath.row])"
        cell.goalCountLabel.text = secondsToGoalTimerLabel(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "goalCountKey"))

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = self.storyboard!
        let nextView =
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        let navi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextView)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! costomViewCell
            print("確認１")

        if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: self.arrayNameKey) {
            print("確認2")
            let arrConversion = arr as! [String]
            print(arrConversion)

            for i in arrConversion {
                if cell.skillName.text! == i {
                    print("確認３")
                }
            }

        }

        present(navi, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: self.arrayNameKey)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addSkillButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        var alertTextFeld: UITextField?
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Skill Name", message: "Enter new name", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addTextField { (textField: UITextField!) in
            alertTextFeld = textField
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            if let text = alertTextFeld?.text {
                self.array.append(text)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: self.arrayNameKey)
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }))

       self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func secret(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }

    func saveDate() {
    }

}
```

**カスタムセルコード**

```swift
import UIKit

class costomViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var skillName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goalCountLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ひとことで申し上げると、条件式の評価値（結果）が`false`だからです。

```
if cell.skillName.text! == i
    { print("確認３") }
    else { print("確認3で、falseとなりました。" }
```

とでもコードを書き加えれば、検証可能になるでしょう。
Swiftの比較演算子（`==`、`!=`）は、左辺右辺あるいは両辺の値が`nil`でもエラーにならないという文法になっていますので、まず`cell.skillName.text!`と`i`が`nil`でないか、調べてみてください。

もうひとつ。配列`arrConversion`の要素数が0の時、`for i in arrConversion`は一度も実行されません。